# Serving my postgres database online

Tags: postgresql, router, forwarding

I want to have a postgres database on a computer that I can use from multiple (external) computers. It will act as a trial server for me, leaving it on whenever I need it.

I researched how to do it and found out I had to forward the service postgres to the internet. Postgres is on port 5432. I logged in my router which has a forwarding option. I opened up the port 5432, but cant add postgres to the list of services.

Is there a reason for that?

Actually. I found that I just have to adapt the pg_hba.conf file (just started trying). I am running windows. Any advise is welcome, this is not my expertise. I dont understand why it would work if I just adapt the pg_hba.conf. For games or other services, like a game, I have to open a port in the router. Or should I do both?

Comment: It's correct that you will need to forward port 5432 traffic on your router to your computer's internal IP and port 5432. Often times routers have a "Custom" port selection in the drop down where you can add your own port numbers. Consult your router's manual. Not sure on the pg_hba.conf, but it won't make a lick of difference if the traffic can't get to the computer. So start at the router, then monkey with the conf.

Comment: You'll likely need to set `listen_addresses = '*'` in `postgresql.conf` since it'll default to `localhost`; edit `pg_hba.conf` to allow external connections *and* forward the port on your router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Postgres documentation - Client authentication is controlled by a configuration file, which traditionally is named pg_hba.conf and is stored in the database cluster's data directory. (HBA stands for host-based authentication.)
Each record specifies a connection type, a client IP address range (if relevant for the connection type), a database name, a user name, and the authentication method to be used for connections matching these parameters.

So it is absolutely required to set up your pg_hba.conf for it to allow access to other computers. You will also need to setup router and firewall settings for allowing incoming connections to port 5432.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do

on postgres.conf change listen_address to:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

and on pg_hba add this to the end of the file

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

And also make sure the port is forwarded to the machine running Postgres from your router